# Cannot uninstall Docker Desktop via Chocolatey

Tags: docker, chocolatey

I've installed Docker 2.4 quite some time ago using Chocolatey (my OS is Win 10). Since updating Docker using `choco upgrade all` always failed, I did the updates manually via the Docker itself (right-click → Check for Updates → etc.). Now I'm on version 3.2.

Since I want to get rid of this manual update process, I wanted to uninstall Docker from Chocolatey. But executing `choco uninstall docker-desktop` fails with `ERROR: Exception calling "GetFullPath" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."`.

Of course, I could uninstall Docker the usual Windows way. But how would I remove Docker from Chocolatey so that I can do a fresh install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by manually uninstalling Docker with default Windows tools.

Afterwards, I deleted the folder `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\docker-desktop`. This resulted in a clean environment when it comes to Docker, because Chocolatey seems to maintain all package-related things in the corresponding `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\<<package>>` folder.

Finally, I could install Docker again via `choco install docker-desktop`.